# When can you determine the cardinality of the compliment of the union of the proper subsets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If you cannot determine the cardinality the union of the (proper) sets and you are not given the cardinality of any compliments of sets, then is it true that you cannot determine the cardinality of the compliment of the union of the proper subsets with respect to the universal set?

I'm have the following as given:
$\\ n(U) = 81 \\
n(A) = 26, n(B) = 40, n(C) = 33\\
n(A \cap B) = 8, n(A \cap C) = 8,n(B \cap C) =7 \\ $

Find $n(A \cap B \cap C)$

So I know that $n(A \cup B \cup C) = n(A) + n(B) + n(C) - n(A \cap B) - n(A \cap C) - n(B \cap C) + n(A \cap B \cap C)$
But, I don't if $U$ is supposed to equal $A \cup B \cup C$.  And, I don't think I can solve this without knowing what $n((A \cup B \cup C)')$ is.  Am I correct?

Comment: You are correct, the best you can get is that $|A \cap B \cap C| \leq 5$. If $U=A \cup B \cup C$, then we will have equality.

Comment: What a nusiance, that new fangled universal set thing.